# NoClassDefFoundError: android.graphics.YuvImage (compiles but doesn't run)

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

i'm reposting this question because i'm not sure if i asked it correctly before.:) i'm working on an app that includes face detection. the camera boots up ok. within the preview frame callback i instantiate a faceview object (this class handles the detection). this class can only detect faces in a bitmap, but the image from the callback is a YuvImage. i've compressed the image to jpeg then called a method to convert that jpeg to a bitmap, so the detection will work.

The problem i'm having is that eclipse is saying that there's a classnotfoundexception regarding the YuvImage that i'm using. i've downloaded the api8 which yuvimage is part of. there are no errors in the source code and it compiles ok. is there a reason why ecilipse can't load the yuvimage class? here's a snippet, thanks.

'code'

```
BitmapFactory.Options bfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Rect rectangle = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(imageData.length);
try{
    img = new YuvImage(imageData,ImageFormat.NV21,width,height,null);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
img.compressToJpeg(rectangle, 100, bos);
byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();


sourceImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
```

Exception trace:

```
02-10 11:53:07.298: ERROR/dalvikvm(2364): Could not find class 'android.graphics.YuvImage', referenced from method com.tecmark.FaceView.<init>
02-10 11:53:07.468: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.graphics.YuvImage
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.tecmark.FaceView.<init>(FaceView.java:60)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.tecmark.cameraView$1.onPreviewFrame(cameraView.java:111)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:395)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-10 11:53:07.473: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2364):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @kgiannakakis thanks, i'm new to forum and not sure how to format things yet:)

Comment: I've fixed the post information. This is a NoClassDefFoundError *runtime error* and not a ClassNotFoundException *exception*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are targeting the proper version of the SDK. In Eclipse right click your project, select Properties and then Android. Api 8 should be selected as the project's build target.

You should also set the minimum SDK attribute in the manifest xml (this has nothing to do with the error though).

Comment: hi, yep i've just checked the properties->android and the api level is 8 and the target name is set to 2.2 is there anything else i could try?

Comment: @turtleboy Is the emulator/device fully 2.2 compliant? Not being so -- (regardless of the project settings) would likely cause this error.

Comment: @pst i just checked the phone and it's firmware version is 2.1. everything in api7 works on the phone but YuvImage is api8 upwards. can 2.1 use api8?

Comment: No, you can't use api8 in a 2.1 phone. You need to update the firmware to do so.

Comment: jesus i've just looked at what needs to be done to upgrade firmware to 2.2, not something i'd like to try:), unless there's an easier website that explains http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/root-samsung-galaxy-spica-i5700-with-leshaks-kernel/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the package `com.tecmark.FaceView` is available to your project. Something like:
`package com.tecmark.FaceView` should be present at the top of your code in this file.

HTH,
Sriram

Comment: yep both classes that i use are in the same package com.tecmark