# NoClassDefFoundError on android/graphics/bitmapfactory

Tags: java, android, bitmap, classnotfoundexception, bitmapfactory

Any ideas why this code won't accept bitmapfactory? All required imports are present. String datatypes can be retrieved in the same query with no issue.

Code in DatabaseConnection.java:

```
Blob blob = result.getBlob(5);
int blobLength = (int) blob.length();  
byte[] blobAsBytes = blob.getBytes(1, blobLength);
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blobAsBytes,0,blobAsBytes.length);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/graphics/BitmapFactory
at com.example.wildtrail.DatabaseConnection.main(DatabaseConnection.java:153)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.graphics.BitmapFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: It looks like that somethig is wrong with the project, try to create anew project and try the code again

Comment: What ADT version do you have?

Comment: I think this link is useful already answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956876/noclassdeffounderror-android-graphics-yuvimage-compiles-but-doesnt-run

Answer (score 0):

`android/graphics/BitmapFactory` is correct and since API 1, but probably you have this issue with ADT 17, this link helped me to solve the problem:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17